# Columnas con diferentes separaciones verticales

Tags: css, css-grid-layout

Tal y como tengo ahora el código con `grid-column-gap: 3%;`, tengo una separación entre cada columna de un 3% y está bien, pero quiero que entre el bloque 2 y el bloque 3 solo haya una separación 1%.

He probado poniendo `grid-column-gap: 3% 1% 3%;` pero no funciona. ¿Alguna idea?

```css
.contenedor {
 margin: 30px; 
 display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 3%;
  grid-row-gap: 5%;
  grid-template-columns: 30% repeat(2, 10%) 30%;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;   
}
.bloque {
 padding: 2%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="bloque">Bloque 1</div>
  <div class="bloque">Bloque 2</div>
  <div class="bloque">Bloque 3</div>
  <div class="bloque">Bloque 4</div>
</div>
```

También deseo que quede centrado con respecto a la pantalla.

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé no puedes hacer eso, el espaciado es para todos el mismo, Puedes tener diferentes espaciados en horizontal y en vertical pero nada más. Lo único que se me ocurre es usar margenes en los elementos que quieras que tengan un espaciado distinto

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sucede que la propiedad `grid-column-gap` no permite más de un valor por grid, es decir no es una propiedad agrupada. [Fuente: Documentación Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-gap) [Documentación Oficial W3C](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#gutters)

Sin embargo podrías solucionarlo usando la propiedad `margin` en negativo para el caso que propones, por ejemplo:

```
.bloque:nth-child(2){ margin-right: -0.5em; } /*o la medida que prefieras*/
.bloque:nth-child(3){ margin-left: -0.5em; } /*o la medida que prefieras*/
```

```css
.contenedor {
 margin: 30px; 
 display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 3%;
  grid-row-gap: 5%;
  grid-template-columns: 30% repeat(2, 10%) 30%;
  grid-template-rows: 100px;   
}
.bloque {
 padding: 2%;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}

.bloque:nth-child(2){ margin-right: -0.25em; }
.bloque:nth-child(3){ margin-left: -0.25em; }
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="bloque">Bloque 1</div>
  <div class="bloque">Bloque 2</div>
  <div class="bloque">Bloque 3</div>
  <div class="bloque">Bloque 4</div>
</div>
```

Muy diferente por ejemplo es usar la propiedad agrupada `grid-gap` (de pronto he ahí la confusión) que combina las propiedades `grid-column-gap` y `grid-row-gap`.